# Magento - Set Original Price in sales order

Tags: php, magento

I have create sales order programmatically.Sales order is generated successfully with all prices, but the Original price column is getting blank. I tried to set in Quote object as well as Order object but no luck.

Can you tell me how can I set original price in sales order.

Thanks!

CODE--

```
    $productModel = Mage::getModel('catalog/product');
$productObj = $productModel->setStore($storeId)->setStoreId($storeId)->load($key);
$productObj->setSkipCheckRequiredOption(true);

$quoteItem = Mage::getModel('sales/quote_item')->setProduct($productObj);
$product_price = $productModel->getPrice();

$quoteItem->setOriginalCustomPrice($product_price);
$quoteItem->setOriginalPrice('2.2'); //NOT SET IN DB
$quoteItem->setCustomPrice($product_price);
$quoteItem->setQty($qty);

$quoteItem->setQuote($quoteObj);
$quoteObj->addItem($quoteItem);

$productObj->unsSkipCheckRequiredOption();
$quoteItem->checkData();


$quoteObj->getShippingAddress()->setCollectShippingRates(true);
$quoteObj->getShippingAddress()->collectShippingRates();
$quoteObj->collectTotals();
$quoteObj->setIsActive(0);
$quoteObj->save();
```

Comment: Please post your code.

Comment: Edit your question, paste the code there, highlight it and click the code button above the edit field for markup. Like this, your code is unreadable and your chance of getting answers is 0.